# Get list of files deleted by rm -rf

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, deleted-files

I hadn't sleep much. A bad script was creating a folder under `somewhere/~` and I tried to removed it with `rm -rf ~`.

I Ctrl C quickly and I don't think I've lost much files. I get they are lost for good. Is there still a way to get a list of the files that got removed?

Comment: In the future, you can use `rm -v` to show what is being removed (e. g. `rm -frv /path/to/directory`).  But I don't believe there's a way to show what's been done after the fact very easily.

Comment: `locate ~` will tell you the list of files in your `$HOME` at the time the `locate` has last updated its database. You can compare that with the actual list of files.  Better than nothing...

Comment: I wished I had setup some kind of backup system: `$locate ~ # WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.`

Comment: @Guig do it now. While you remember the frustration.

Comment: No, **do not** set up `locate` right now. Don't write anything to the file system if you can help it at all. **Rule number one of data recovery is to not write to the affected storage device, at all.** Image the partition if you can, and work on a copy of the image. That way, if you mess up, you will be able to get back to where you started, instead of having made an *even bigger* mess. // cc @roaima

Comment: By all means set up locate later, if you want to (it is a useful tool at times). Also, you really should set up a automated, recurring backup scheme. But don't do that now, while doing so could overwrite critical pieces of the files you are trying to recover. Recover your data first, then take steps to make sure you don't lose it again.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I was intending my remark to address the lack of a backup, not the `locate` side-issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I Ctrl C quickly and I don't think I've lost much files. I get they are lost for good. Is there still a way to get a list of the files that got removed?

There is no easy way to "list" what you have deleted. You could do an `extundelete /dev/home_partition(sdx) --restore-all` to try to recover your data, or follow this extensive answer with a more "safe" approach to manage your deleted data:

- [accidental fsck on mounted](https://superuser.com/a/433785/210242)

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) is your friend too on this quest;

Answer (score 3):

If `locate` is installed and a daily cron job runs `updatedb` to update the list and it has run before your `rm` and not after, you could try:

```
locate -0 ~/\* | perl -l -0 -ne 'print unless lstat$_'
```

to get an idea of the damage.

That is, find the files in the `locate` database that are no longer there.

With GNU `locate` (not `mlocate`), you can shorten it to:

```
locate -E ~/\*
```

Comment: Alright, I can see now from the comments to your questions that you didn't have `locate` enabled. I'm still leaving the answer for the benefit of other people in the same situation.

Answer (score -2):

Even though I can't get an exact list of the files that got removed, I can see the one that are remaining with `ls -fa ~`. Since the order in which files gets removed is known (it's the same you'd get files listed with `ls -f`) I can know until where `rm` went. So

```
$ ls -fa ~
.
..
.cocoapods
...
```

So everything up to `.cocoapods`, plus some things within that folder got removed.  For me that means I'm quite lucky since this is mainly `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` which I can partially recover from `printenv` and `alias`

Pfiou!

Comment: No. There was nothing in the original command that mandated an alphanumeric sort on the filenames. Without checking the source to `rm`, I'd suggest it's likely files (and directories) were removed in directory order.

Comment: What do you call directory order? I've looked at a number of questions around this that suggest that for most of the shell, including bash, `ls -fa` gives a reliable ordering

Comment: @roaima `ls -f` disables the sorting. However, as you point out, that doesn't say anything about what files were deleted: it may well be that `ls -f` would have listed `~/zoo` and `~/very-important` before `~/.cocoapods`.